# Using a console application to reference a VB.net exe form function

Tags: c#

I am very new to referencing dll's and .exe's.  I have an application that sends reports to users on a daily basis.  This is a manual process, and I have been tasked to automate that process.  Now, I would like to create a console application, and reference that form that does the work on the .exe.  I am so lost on how to do this.  Can anyone provide me with a sample or tutorial on how to do this?

Comment: What about using the windows task scheduler? Simply schedule the execution of the executable...

Comment: Every dll and exe is different, can you give more details on the application you are trying to automate? Does it just run or does it require user input? Is it Windows Form/Console Application/WPF etc?

Comment: Also, if the application you are trying to automate is well written, you won't be able to just add it as a reference to another Project and run the methods and access the fields, as they will be private/internal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a reference to VB.net assembly (*.exe file) in your console application project, inspect it with object browser and call required method.

To add a reference, right click on reference folder of your project :)

[image]

Comment: I have added it as a reference, but I need to know what to do next?  I want to know how to call a procedure that is found on the code behind for a form on the other application.

Comment: Double click on the reference item in reference folder. Object inspector will be opened. Find the method you need.